# Confusion regarding the definition of tensor product of modules.

Tags: modules, definition, tensor-products

We are having a module theory course in MSc. Mathematics.Our instructor introduced it as follows:

Let, $M,N$ be $R$-modules ,then $T$ (also an $R$-module) is said to be a tensor product of $M$ and $N$ if for any $R$-module $P$ and any bilinear map $f:M\times N\to P$ ,there exists a bilinear map $\varphi:M\times N\to T$ such that $\exists$ $! g:T\to P$ linear such that $f=g\circ \varphi$.

But I am not sure whether I have noted it correctly or what it means(if at all it is correct).Can someone clarify the definition and give me some idea of what we are trying to do?

Comment: You should really ask your instructor! That's the whole point of being an instructor, really. Never let anyone introduce you a concept without telling you what it means and what you are trying to do: it is an extreme waste of your time and hers.

Comment: The order of quantifiers is wrong. The map $\varphi$ does not depend upon $f$.

Comment: @blargoner So,can you please write the correct definition for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post, I'm going to assume that $R$ is commutative. A tensor product of the $R$-modules $M$ and $N$ is a pair $(T,\varphi)$ where $T$ is an $R$-module and $\varphi:M\times N\to T$ is a universal bilinear map on $M\times N$, in the sense that for any $R$-module $P$ and bilinear map $f:M\times N\to P$, there is a unique linear map $g:T\to P$ with $f=g\circ\varphi$. The tensor product is unique up to unique isomorphism, and we write $T=M\otimes N$ and $\varphi=\otimes$.

Intuitively, $M\otimes N$ is "universal" because it is the "most general" $R$-module obtained from a bilinear product between $M$ and $N$ -- every other such product is obtained through the tensor product $\otimes$ in a unique way.